# how do you style your kendoUI combobox?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-2.0

here's my kendoUI combobox using mvc3  wrapper.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x.K1State)
                           .Name("ddK1State")
                           .DataTextField("Name")
                           .DataValueField("Id")
                           .BindTo((List<StateVM>)ViewData["State"])
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-small", @Id = "ddK1State", @style = "width:88px;" })
                           .Events(events => events.Change("onK1StateChange")))
```

I can use class and style.

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-small", @Id = "ddK1State", @style = "width:88px;" })
```

I change it using kendo-knockout.js file.

```
<input data-bind=" kendoComboBox: { enabled: k1Address.isStateMutable,  dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id', data: states, value: k1Address.stateId, htmlAttributes: 'new {style=\'width: 88px;\'}'}" />
```

the style is not working. I couldn't find "htmlAttributes" in combobox docs, probably thats why its not working.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the style directly to the input element?

```
<input style="width:80px" ... />
```

There is no such conception as HtmlAttributes with the JavaScript widget - it's just used in the MVC world.